# storing a constant in memory using ASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, mov

What would be the proper gcc compilable GAS ASM code to store my constant  $3360220 in a memory location 0x7FFFFFFFb098?
Will this produce the desired result? Is it ok that the movabs instruction "spills" on the next line?
added question: my disassembled code looks like this eventhough i wrote

```
jmp 0x401070
```

, why is that and how do i fix it? it also converted my movq to movabs

```
   0:   49 c7 c1 dc 45 33 00    mov    $0x3345dc,%r9
   7:   49 ba 98 f0 ff ff ff    movabs $0x7fffffff098,%r10
   e:   07 00 00 
  11:   4d 89 0a                mov    %r9,(%r10)
  14:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   0x19
```

I made the .d file in linux x86-64 using `objdump -d file.o > file.d`. How do I use the proper linking?

I mistyped the address at first missing the "b" in the hex.Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem pushing the address on the stack and returning.

```
0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   49 c7 c1 dc 45 33 00    mov    $0x3345dc,%r9
   7:   4c 8d 54 24 08          lea    0x8(%rsp),%r10
   c:   4d 89 0a                mov    %r9,(%r10)
   f:   ff 34 25 70 10 40 00    pushq  0x401070
  16:   c3                      retq
```

The problem was that **one cannot easily specify a 64bit address in a jmp instruction**.
The assembler does not know where is this code going to be, it sets aside 32-bits for a near jump and adds a relocation section that tells the linker to update this region with the correct data.

Answer (score 0):

To store constant **$3360220** in memory location **0x7FFFFFFF098**, you want something like:

```
mov $3360220, %rax
movabs %rax, 0x7fffffff098
```

You're

```
jmp 0x401070
```

looks like:

```
14:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   0x19
```

because you disassembled the **.o** file. If you disassemble it after the linker is done with relocation processing, it'll look *normal*:

```
0x00000000004000e5 <+17>:   e9 86 0f 00 00  jmpq   0x401070
```

Comment: error, operand size mismatch for movabs says my gcc. Thank you for the info about the missing linker. So my code would not work properly without assembly linker routine i guess.